# AVSpeechSynthesizer - does not stop when using AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I have two view controllers. One and Two.

1. On oneViewController, there is a button that calls TwoViewController using Storyboard - working fine
2. On TwoViewController there is a button that reads some text using a button (Listen Button) - working fine
3. There is Back button on TwoViewController that takes you back to oneViewController.

Issue:

if Listen Button is clicked twice and Back button is pressed, the view controller goes from Two to One, but the speech is still going on in the background. Can someone help with a way to stop the speech?

Code On TwoViewController:

AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth;

```
-(IBAction) Back:(id)sender
{
    [_synth stopSpeakingAtBoundary: AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate]; --not working
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; - working fine.
}

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_synth stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate]; --not working
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)listenButton:(id)sender
{
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"I am running a test."];
    [utterance setRate:0.18f];
    _synth=[[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    [_synth speakUtterance:utterance];

}
```

Note: the issue does not happen if the Listen Button is clicked once and then Back button is clicked. Issue happens only if Listen button is clicked multiple times and then Back button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for pause ,resume and stop options

```
-(void)stopSpeechReading
{
    if([synthesize isSpeaking]) {
        NSLog(@"Reading has been stopped");
        [synthesize stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@""];
        [synthesize speakUtterance:utterance];
        [synthesize stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
    }
}

-(void)pauseSpeechReading
{
    if([synthesize isSpeaking]) {
        NSLog(@"Reading paused");
        [synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@""];
        [synthesize speakUtterance:utterance];
        [synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
    }
}

-(void)resumeSpeechReading
{
     NSLog(@"Reading resumed");
    [synthesize continueSpeaking];
}
```